# How to reduce the font size of superscripts within a line of a reference number?

Tags: fonts, biblatex

Want to reduce the font size of a reference no. which has been used as a superscript within a line. In the attached image want to make the font size of 22 little smaller than the usual one (such as 23 reference no.). 
command used: $^{\scriptstyle\cite{reference}}$.[image: font size of the reference]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE...Can you provide `MWE` of your code? It will help to do detail analyse the issue ...

Comment: If you are really using `biblatex` as your tagging suggests, use `\supercite{reference}` instead of `$^{\scriptstyle\cite{reference}}$`. If you want more useful/more specific advice you will need to tell us more about your document: Which citation/bibliography packages do you load, which style do you use? This is best done in a short example document that shows a citation with as little other code as possible, a so-called MWE, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864.

Comment: Any news here? Unfortunately, it is not clear whether you are using `biblatex` or a different way to produce your bibliography (the `biblatex` tag is often misused). Since answers will differ depending on the system you use, this question can not be answered properly without more knowledge about your system. Please post an MWE (see my comment above for helpful links). If there is no development here in due time I will vote to close as *unclear what you are asking*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as *unclear what you are asking* since the question is lacking important information about the used citation/bibliography package and the style. I'll happily vote to reopen if more information is provided (preferably in the form of an MWE), just give me a ping.